# Software license support when redistributing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, license

I'm trying to distribute the device, which includes Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and proprietary software.

According to my research, Ubuntu18.04LTS contains over 2000 software license files,
It takes a great deal of effort to understand the contents of all these licenses and respond appropriately.

I haven't made any changes to the project on the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I looked on the license page of Ubuntu's official page to see 
if there were any guidelines for displaying the license of the software included in Ubuntu or disclosing the source, 
but I couldn't find any such guidelines.
https://ubuntu.com/licensing

Let me know how to deal with the software license when redistributing Ubuntu18.04 LTS.

Comment: Does https://ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy answer your questions?

Comment: There it is written. "Ubuntu is an aggregate work of many works, each covered by their own licence(s). For the purposes of determining what you can do with specific works in Ubuntu, this policy should be read together with the licence(s) of the relevant packages. "Is it my understanding that you should read the licenses of the more than 2000 files that Ubuntu contains and make the license notices and source disclosures accordingly?

Comment: One would recommend paying a lawyer for professional advice if untangling thousands of licences is an important question. In general, Ubuntu and it's packages can be redistributed freely for commercial and non-commercial use. There are exceptions (Example: The game *simutrans* cannot be distributed commercially). Stock Ubuntu is used daily by many enterprise customers and in a wide assortment of products. WARNING: I am not a licensed lawyer in whatever jurisdiction you happen to be located in, and I do not speak for Canonical.